# Continuous image of a Paracompact space need not be Paracompact.

Tags: general-topology

The following is an exercise in Topology by Munkres.

- Show that if *f* is a continuous map from **X** to **Y** where **X** is paracompact then the subspace *f*(**X**) of **Y** need not be paracompact.

I am having trouble constructing such a function. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

HINT: Every discrete space is paracompact, and every map whose domain is a discrete space is continuous. Find a non-paracompact space $Y$ and just ...

Comment: Oh!Thank You. I feel stupid now.

Comment: @user20694: We’ve all been there a time or two. :-)